# Download file in ReactJS app preserving the original filename

Tags: reactjs, blob

I'm serving pdf file with nodejs/koa2

```
      ctx.body = readableStream;
      ctx.attachment('file.pdf');
```

The file successfully arrives and on the client side i receive it with ReactJS application:

```
  const document = useSelector(selectors.getFile(documentFile.key));
  if (document) {
    window.open(window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([document], { type: "application/octet-stream" })), "_self");
  }
...
  const openFile = useCallback((key) => {
    dispatch(actions.getFile.request(key))
  }, [dispatch]);
```

It successfully downloads the file, but completely ignores response header `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.pdf"` and downloads it under the name like `d3aa7870-bd35-4645-a926-294392343cfc` which is taken from the BLOB url: `Request URL: blob:http://localhost:3000/d3aa7870-bd35-4645-a926-294392343cfc`.

Could you please advise how to correctly save it under the name of `file.pdf` on the client side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just create an  element and set download attribute with file name

```js
  const document = useSelector(selectors.getFile(documentFile.key));
  if (document) {
    const url =window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([document], { type: "application/octet-stream" }))
    const a = document.createElement("a");
    a.style = "display: none";
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.href = url;
    a.download = "fileName";
    a.click();
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
  }
```